# LLVM Scalar Evolution (SCEV) for array access

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I am experimenting with SCEV and wanted to identify the array access patterns using it.
I have used SCEV on the below instruction

```
%arrayidx3 = getelementptr inbounds i32, i32* %6, i64 %idxprom2
```

and got the below SCEV dump

```
((4 * (sext i32 (3 + %7) to i64))<nsw> + %6)
```

Question :

I want to access constant '3' from the above expression, how to do that ?

Comment: The top-level return value will probably be an Instruction. Try calling [getOperand(0)](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1User.html#abe1de1520a21f77ac57cc210bf0fb0b4)->[dump()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Value.html#af7dca9a9e816ef69fd9e9467f64f72b4), you ought to get the first parenthesis and %6 if you call getOperand(1). That first parenthesis is also an Instruction, and you can work your way in. You can find the kind of instruction too... in several ways actually, isa<> is one. This isn't a complete answer, but play around a bit, you'll get the hang of it.

Comment: Thanks @arnt , I figured it out just after some time posting the question here. I did exactly the way you suggested !  But I thought there will be some simple matcher/regex kind of infrastructure for this.

Comment: Quite frankly I don't think this kind of task is amenable to a simple general matcher. I've done it many times and no two times were really similar.